# hooking drupal commerce coupon pane

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I try to make a small change to Drupal Commerce Coupon pane (add a div to it). I tried to hook this function:

```
    function commerce_coupon_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
              // Allow to replace pane content with ajax calls.
              $pane_form = array(
                '#prefix' => '<div id="commerce-checkout-coupon-ajax-wrapper">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>',
              );
        (..)
}
```

To do this I created a function in my module:

```
function <mymodule>_form_commerce_coupon_pane_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="collapsable-panel"><p>You have coupon? Add it here.</p>' + $form['#prefix'];
        $form['#suffix'] = $form['#suffix'] + '</div>';
    }
```

but it do not work. I think that there should be other way to hook checkout pane but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is correct, however the ID of the form is incorrect. It should be like this `function <mymodule>_form_commerce_coupon_pane_checkout_alter`.

If it still doesn't work, here's an alternative to try:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == "YOU NEED TO DISCOVER THE FORM ID") {
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

Don't forget to clear all caches!

Comment: Unfortunately for Drupal Commerce it doesn't work that way. form in commerce_coupon_pane_checkout_form is confusing because in fact in don't handle form but is used to create part of one big checkout form. It took me some time to figure out how to handle this task, finally I posted correct answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178025/how-to-hook-checkout-pane-defined-in-another-module